# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, php-openssl

I am trying to send an email using Mailer but getting below error

> Connection: opening 2017-05-25 08:22:07   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect
>   to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect()
>   failed.

php_openssl extension & IMAP both are enabled. I tried to find it on google but still no luck.

Code:

```
function sendMail($subject='',$to='',$emailcontent='',$attach='')
{
    global $_mailmsg;
    //echo $emailcontent;exit;
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
    $mail->isSMTP();                                    
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = '465';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'xx@gmail.com';                            
    $mail->Password = 'xxxx';                           
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                                  
    $mail->From = 'xx@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Test';
    $mail->addAddress($to);  // Add a recipient
    if(!empty($cc)){    $mail->addCC($cc); }
    if(!empty($bcc)){   $mail->addBCC($bcc);    }

    $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
    if($attach != ''){
        $mail->addAttachment($attach);    
    }
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');   
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = 'Test';
    try
    {
        if($mail->send()) {
            return 1;
           exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return 0;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check your IMAP Access settings of your gmail account? Go to Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> IMAP Access -> Enable IMAP and click Save Changes button.

Comment: @KorayKüpe : Yes it's enabled

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your server is not permitted to connect to remote SMTP servers, something very common at big ISPs like GoDaddy. If you do the steps described in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) you can figure out what's blocking you. The fact that there is no link to the guide in your error message tells me that you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

PHPMailer has nothing to do with IMAP; that's for inbound mail only.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Gmail, just turn on "Allow less secure apps":

https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps

And also you'll probably need to allow access to your Google account without unlock captcha:

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha